# A required anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid when deployed on IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, cookies

I have an MVC application.

I have `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` on each Post action.

When i run it on my local computer, it is working well. The problem is when i deploy it to my development server. I am encountering the Required anti-forgery token error.

Is there something that i must configure in IIS in order for my application to work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You also need to include the Antiforgery token in the forms you want to protect, i.e.

```
<%= Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>
```

You must include the above in your forms that post through to the controller actions that are decorated with the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute as illustrated below:

```
<% using(Html.Form("{ControllerHere}", "{ActionHere}")) { %>
     <%= Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>
     <!-- rest of form goes here -->
<% } %>
```